# Power Arduino Nano 3 externally

Tags: arduino

I want to buy an Arduino Nano 3 but it seems that it can be powered only by USB.

I want to use it in some places where I don't have a computer so I can't power the Arduino.

- Can I use  the VIN pin to power it?
- What voltage should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [board's manual](http://site.gravitech.us/Arduino/NANO30/Arduino_Nano3_0.pdf), pin 30 is VIN, which is in range 7-12V, or the pin 27 can be used as 5V output (if powered by VIN), or 5V input from external power supply. I strongly recommend to read related documentation before working with any new hardware.

Comment: I'm new to this. What is an external PS?

Comment: PS = power supply

Comment: And where can I connect the external power supply? Do you have a diagram which can help me?

Comment: Pin 30 is +7V to 12V, pin 29 is GND. If you want to locate them, look at the manual and/or the board's schematic.

Answer (score 1):

How Eugene Sh. told you, you can give the power supply to your Arduino Nano (Rev.3 and previous) applying +5V DC on the correspondent pin and GND.
You can also give the Power Supply applying voltage up to +12 V DC or on the VIn pin and GND. This is one good solution for the beginners that cannot use the USB as source of Power.

But there is also the solution to use a wall USB Power Supply (the battery charger of your phone) connected to the USB of your Arduino Nano.

Be careful!

Answer (score -1):

As long as you dont have a long distance to run, I would use a USB wall adapter rated for 5V.  If it's not too far use a USB extension which is about 4 to 6 feet long. The VIN and GND are an option but I only would do this if I could guarantee 5 volts.  They say 5 to 12 but I would not trust that, that is totally up to you.

Comment: This is one of those questions if you look you will get lots of answers many not correct. I prefer using the Vin with 8 to 12 VDC, it is NOT a 5V input. That gives me extra filtering and protects it if I get a glitch in the power supply. Connecting directly to the 5V works but you have added an antenna that will pick up stray EMF (electrical noise). There are also many variations that are called Nano and they are not all the same. The best thing to do is get the datasheet and schematic for the part you have. I always do this and file it with the project papers along with source and libraries.